# print in console all the function which is being executed in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating **`AngularJS Javascript`** application in which i have 500/600  function in a single Directive,

Many functions are Inter connected with each other,
flow starts from the On load Event,

I want to know when i run the project,
which functions are being called on **`Onload Event`**

and i want to print the same on console,

> I google it but i am not able to get anything,

is there any way to find out the functions which is being executed?

Comment: You can try to use google chrome profiler. 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/js-execution

Comment: Inside each function, you can insert `console.log('function ' + arguments.callee.name);`

Comment: @evilReiko but this will be very lengthy and doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all your functions into *"log wrapper"*:

```
var self = this;
function LogWrapper(action){ 
    return function(){
        console.log(action.name); 
        return action.apply(self, arguments);
    }
}

//usage:
function ActualFunctionInner(arg1, arg2){
    //some logic
}
var ActualFunction = LogWrapper(ActualFunctionInner);
var result = ActualFunction(1, 2);//console: ActualFunctionInner
```

Second solution is via `Proxy`:

```
let handler = {
       get(target, propKey) {
            var inner = target[propKey];
            return function () {
                console.log(inner.name);
                return inner.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        }
    };
var loggedSelf = new Proxy(self, handler);
var result = loggedSelf.ActualFunction(1, 2);//console: ActualFunction
```

Answer (score 0):

Call console.trace('calling on-load') to find stack-trace on on-load function. It would be better to call trace on the last function you expect to be executed to find all other function which has been called before.